# Direct State Access version of glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: opengl

Considering there is a DSA version of `glEnableVertexAttrib`, is there a DSA version for a function that specifies attribute layout that I'm missing?

Comment: [`glVertexArrayAttribFormat`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribFormat.xhtml) and [`glVertexArrayAttribBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexBuffer.xhtml) sound like what you're looking for. Each one allows direct state access on a vertex array object